# how to pass multiple values in google map popup window with button to pass id values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i have enclosed my code when i click marker i should show Madivala, 12.914494, 77.560381,car,as12 with one button it should pass id values how can i solve some one help me out to move forward
http://jsfiddle.net/cLADs/123/

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&v=3.0&sensor=true&language=ee"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    #map-canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
  </style>




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Madivala', 12.914494, 77.560381, 'car','as12'],
    ['1', 'Majestic', 12.961229, 77.559281, 'third','as13'],
    ['2', 'Ecity', 12.92489905, 77.56070772, 'car','as14'],
    ['3', 'Jp nagar', 12.91660662, 77.52047465, 'second','as15']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667,77.5667);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
}//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Please select category</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="third">third</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pen answers you questions and print to the console as you requested:
http://codepen.io/Saar/pen/OyNeEY?editors=101

```
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Madivala', 12.914494, 77.560381, 'car','as12'],
    ['1', 'Majestic', 12.961229, 77.559281, 'third','as13'],
    ['2', 'Ecity', 12.92489905, 77.56070772, 'car','as14'],
    ['3', 'Jp nagar', 12.91660662, 77.52047465, 'second','as15']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667,77.5667);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];
    var fullContent = marker.slice(1,6).join();

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, idx, markers1) {
  return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            var compiled = '<div><div>' +markers1[idx][0] + ' </div><div>' + markers1[idx][1] + ' </div><div>' +markers1[idx][2] + ' </div><div><button onclick="getid(markers1[' + idx + '][5])">Get</button></div></div>';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: compiled
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1,i, markers1));
}
function getid(id) {
console.log(id)
}
/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

Comment: it should come 
Majestic,12.961229,77.559281,third,as13 one by one and i want to add one button it should pass values 0,1,2,3,4 based on marker click

Comment: in that pop up window i need one button <button ng-click="getid(marker1[' + i + '][0])">Get</button> it should pass id value based on marker click (0,1,2,3,4) $scope.getid = function(id) {
console.log(id);                        
                    }

Comment: sorry, still having trouble understanding your goal. if you want a custom element on the map you can use this API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

Comment: now when i click marker popup coming,in that popup how to add one button it should pass id value <button ng-click="getid(marker1[' + i + '][0])">Get</button>

Comment: checkout this fiddle, notice I used the example I gave you and on click of a marker I added a button on top, hope that you can manage from here: http://jsfiddle.net/cLADs/134/

Comment: within this 
Majestic,12.961229,77.559281,third,as13 .how to add one button it should pass value

Comment: I did a small fix for you, you had some issues with closures, check my codepen: http://codepen.io/Saar/pen/OyNeEY?editors=101

Comment: id is not priniting in console

Comment: when i click get nothing i am getting please check

Comment: Now it prints to the console as you requested as well.

Comment: how can i convert to angular